# How to use buffer in assembly (GNU asm)?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to use buffer in read sys call, but it seems it didn't get recognized.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text

.lcomm buffer, 2048

.globl main
.type  main, @function

main:
  mov    al,SYS_read
  mov    bl,0x3
  mov    ecx,buffer
  mov    dl,12
  int    0x80
```

fd is assumed to be 3. The problem is when using "gcc -m32 -o -c" to compile it to object file. the "mov ecx,buffer" is always compiled into 8B0D00000000, buffer is referred as all zeros. I think it didn't know the buffer variable is defined.

Comment: The address will be filled in by the linker. If you want to look at object file, ask for relocation information using `objdump -dr`.

Comment: so you think the syntax (.lcomm and just use "buffer" to refer to it) is correct?

Comment: Since you want the address not a value from it, you should use `mov ecx, offset buffer`. The syntax is correct but that would be a load from memory.

Comment: @ASMLearner Yes, it is (modulo what Jester said).  Try linking your program into an executable.  The address should be filled in by the linker.

Comment: You are writing to the lowest 8 bits of your argument registers (`al`, `bl`, `cl`).  You cannot assume that the upper parts will be zeroed, and if they are not, your code will fail, possibly subtly, possibly spectacularly.